# Is there away to filter a list of products in a list of categorys? Angular Pipeline

Tags: angular, typescript, list, filter, pipeline

Here My Pipeline:

```
export class MyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: Array<CatalogItemsWithCategory>, searchfilter: string): Array<CatalogItemsWithCategory> {
        

        if (!items || !searchfilter) {
            return items;
        }

        else if(searchfilter == "")
        {
          return items;
        }

        items = items.filter(items => items.catalogItems.forEach.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchfilter.toLowerCase()) !== -1);


        return items;
    }
}
```

Here my product class:

```
export interface ICatalogFlat {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    catalogNumber: number;
    description: string;
    requiresApproval: boolean;
    status: ProductStatus;
    images: Array<string>;
    category: ICategory;
    imageIndex: number;
    endDate: Date | null;
    startDate: Date;
}
```

Here my category class:

```
export interface CatalogItemsWithCategory {
    catalogItems: ICatalogFlat[];
    categoryName: string;
}
```

I want to type in the searchbar and then filter on the product names. So i need to filter a list in a list but still want the filterd products in the list of categorys.

Comment: What is the issue? This pipe not working?

Comment: I would like to filter the products in a list of categorys with a searchterm. But the way i tried did not work.

Comment: I tried with a foreach in the filter function but it didnt work

Comment: Can you share items array?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
export class MyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: Array<CatalogItemsWithCategory>, searchfilter: string): Array<CatalogItemsWithCategory> {

        if (!items || !searchfilter) {
            return items;
        }

        else if (searchfilter == "") {
            return items;
        }

        const returnItems: any[] = [];
        for (const item of items) {
            const returnCatalogItems = [];
            for (const catalogItem of item.catalogItems) {
                if (catalogItem.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchfilter) > -1) {
                    returnCatalogItems.push(catalogItem);
                }
            }

            returnItems.push({ ...item, catalogItems: returnCatalogItems });
        }


        return returnItems;
    }
}
```

Comment: When i use this and i type something in the searchbar it crashes